# How to avoid breaking block level HTML elements from partial selection?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ckeditor

The problem in a nutshell is: given a wysiwyg editor (CKEditor) you want to make a plugin doing text transformation - select a piece of text and manipulate the text in it (eg uppercase). Example:

> this is paragraph **one**
>
> **this** is paragraph two

If bold represents your selection the result would be

> this is paragraph **ONE**
>
> **THIS** is paragraph two

This issue here is the selection will be a complete HTML fragment, even when a selection is no containing the full tag. The selected HTML is:

```
<p>one</p> <p>this</p>
```

Notice the first and last `<p>` tags. When you do your dom traverse in the selection html, apply the text transformation and replace the html it will use those partial tags, so your result become:

> this is paragraph
>
> **ONE**
>
> **THIS**
>
> is paragraph two

I checked if it's possible to "merge" the first and last partial tags with their dom parents, however the selection object is isolated, it doesn't have siblings or parents from it's original context.

Also tried to find an option to retrieve the selection without these auto-fixed tags, but no luck.

On the CKEditor documentation they mention a [walker object](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.walker) - however that automatically expands from the selection to the full enclosing tag, which means the selection is only used as a minimum boundary.

Also because the selection object is isolated, it's not possible to just change the dom node text values there - the original dom fragment needs to be replaced (at least in case of CKEditor).

I tried not to stick with the CKEditor api as much as possible, however at this point I don't see any alternatives either. Is this is really a hard problem or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the browser engine to mark the selected area with a tag (afaik that's a native operation). This is the same as you make your selection bold or italic - however here it's gonna be a temporary wrapper. Then you walk the DOM and replace the content in the temporary tags - and finally remove the tag (keeping the content).

This makes sure you can apply your transformation on the exact selection and by removing the tag you won't break the original DOM. Steps in a nutshell:

1. apply tag on selection (use the browser or wysiwyg api)
2. find all temp tags:

   - recursively walk the children of the tag

     - if tag is text node then apply transformation
     - otherwise recursive walk
   - collect tag's left sibling text node + tag's html + right sibling text node
   - replace tag's parent html with the previous compilation (=remove temp tag)

Not too elegant however works. This is inspired by @Andrew_Mast's idea about wrapping in a span.

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through all of the word(s) and for each set of words inside a different tag, surround it with `<span style="text-transform: uppercase;">` and `</span>`

Comment: Hi Andrew, not sure I understand. If you refer to separating the elements by wrapping them, it will still have the problem of containing the block level html tags. Otherwise here I'm looking for a text transformation - html tag changes are already well supported by the low level browser dom apis. Let me know if I misunderstood. Cheers

Comment: How about surrounding it with `<span style="text-transform: uppercase;">` and `</span>`

Comment: Andrew - that works in some case - eg for uppercase, but for example not for custom transformations that are not supported by css. Uppercase was probably a misleading example, I need custom text transformation ability.

Comment: Like a custom transformation function? Please explain

Comment: For example apply a custom regexp on all words in the selection.